# connect to db using the db name from the custom config name

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-database

In my

> application/config/config.php

I have this custom config item

```
$config['roles_permissions_db'] = 'roles_permissions';
```

and I'm trying to connect to a db using

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->database($CI->config->item('roles_permissions_db'),TRUE);
```

and I have set-up database connection for 'roles_permissions' as well unto the database config (application/config/database.php)

```
$db['roles_permissions']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['roles_permissions']['username'] = "root";
$db['roles_permissions']['password'] = "";
$db['roles_permissions']['database'] = "roles_permissions";
```

but everytime I run, it throws me this error

> you did not specify a database connection yet

but if I do this,

```
 $CI->load->database('roles_permissions',TRUE);
```

it works. Any ideas, help please?

Comment: Can you confirm the result of `$this->config->item('roles_permissions_db')`

Comment: Yes, i did var_dump and it gives me "roles_permissions"

Comment: I highly suspect that there is a typo somewhere, can you like create to variables and load the database using the Config library and using the string directly and check the result.

Comment: Am using latest codeigniter, I didn't had this problem. which version of codeigniter you are using?

Comment: Can you check what you have set in database config as active group?

Comment: can u pls show your controller code for how u using `$this->load->database('roles_permissions',TRUE);` i have tested just like u did and its working fine

Comment: @RayA im using 3

Comment: update it to 3.1.9, it should work fine

Comment: @Skalbhile yes  $CI->load->database('roles_permissions',TRUE);

Comment: I'm loading it unto my helper so I'm using $CI =& get_instance(); FYI

Comment: updated my post, please refer above

Comment: can you show you helper full code?

Comment: first of all you don't need to load database again if you are using same database in helper, still if you want to load - you need to pass group name in database() function eg. `$this->load->database('group_name');`

Answer (score 0):

I hope below will help you....

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'database_name',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => TRUE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array()
);
```

please refer below documents for more details on database connection.
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/connecting.html